# How can I set a concurrency "weight" in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I can run multiple jobs concurrently by configuring the number of executors. However, I have this one job that uses an extraordinary amount of memory, so whenever that job is running I want no other jobs to be running. How can I do this?

I have already tried the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin, but it seems that plugin only throttles the concurrency of the project itself, not the concurrency of *other* projects.

I have seen the lock plugin, but I can't use that, because I want jobs to execute concurrently (in order to maximize CPU utilization), *except* when that one extra-memory-heavy job is running.

So what I actually want is to set the "concurrency weight" of a job. Whenever that job is running, I want Jenkins to reserve X executors, where X is the weight I set.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have gotten around this is to use the Heavy Job plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin

Giving the "high memory" job the **same** weight as there are executors, meaning that when the "high memory" job is scheduled, it'll wait until that number of executors are available (all of them, in this case, so no other jobs are running) and then **consume** all the executors as it does it's thing - ensuring **no other jobs can run at the same time on that box**.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I'm looking for.